# What are some good ways to prevent public access to server / app?

Tags: security

What are some good ways to prevent public access to a server / app ?

i know i can set up an ssh tunnel, but this requires me to setup a proxy on my local machine and point my browser to it. this is no good since some non devs need to see the app.

i'm talking about preventing access to an app (in a staging environment) that doesn't require much technical work from viewers.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

#### edit

By preventing access i mean, no one except machines i choose can access the application, i don't mean authentication, i'm sure stackexchange does this, i know they did this once using `X-Forwarded-For` header and checking for `127.0.0.1` ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a SSL/TLS VPN or IPsec VPN is a good solution. Just set your app to use a private IP and it will not be publicly routeable. Also this way your users can just connect to the VPN via a shortcut and providing a user name and password. Using some hosts entries on the VPN server you can direct traffic from a domain to the local IP that serves the app. Implement Public Key Infrastructure and your users will only be able to authenticate if they have a key.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the IP address(es) that your developers will be connecting from, why not just firewall it off from everybody except them?

Comment: yeah, but ip's change, can i ensure they use a certain ip ?

Comment: Depends on where they're connecting from I guess. If you don't want to use authentication, and you want to basically make the app unavailable to people other than those you specify, then you're going to need some kind of network level solution, whether that's firewall rules or a VPN tunnel for those you allow access.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTTP Basic Authentication:

1. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

This has the advantage of letting you give access to others with their own credentials easily, and you don't need to edit the firewall rules.

Comment: thanks, but i'm asking to prevent complete access, i will edit and explain myself better.

Comment: Reading your edit, it seems that you either want HTTP Basic Authentication (you give a username and password to each user, which can be set as part of the URL: `http://user:pass@yoursite.com/yourapp.php`) or you want to filter on IP address.

Comment: so there's no "other ways", the problem with basic auth is that anyone can see there's an app, and it requests username and password.`

Comment: That problem is common to any other way. I suppose that you could use PHP to show an innocuous page if there is no authentication given, and serve the app only if authentication is given.